# How can I specify the load balancer for a CloudWatch alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am trying to create a Cloud Formation template that includes Cloud Watch alarms based on specific metrics from specific load balancers. My question is how do I specify the load balancer for each alarm? I'm pretty sure you have to specify the ARN somewhere but I'm not sure how to reference the ARN from load balancers in different stacks or where to reference them. I am pretty new to AWS services so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
"500ErrorAlarmEast": {
        "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
        "Properties" : {
            "AlarmName" : "500ErrorAlarm",
            "ComparisonOperator" : "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
            "EvaluationPeriods" : 1,
            "MetricName" : "HTTPCode_ELB_500_Count",
            "Namespace" :  { "Ref": "AlarmNamespace" },
            "Period" : 300,
            "Statistic" : "Sum",
            "Threshold" : 5,
            "AlarmDescription" : "Unusually high level of internal 500 ALB East errors.",
            "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref": "SnsTopic" } ],
            "TreatMissingData" : "notBreaching",
            "InsufficientDataActions" : []
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the dimension parameter
"Dimensions": [
{
"Name": "LoadBalancer",
"Value": {
"Ref": "WebAppALBId"
}
}
],